# Count the amount of records are associated to another record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, methods, count

In my Ruby on Rails application I am creating a cinema system, and on the bookings/new page I am allowing the user to choose the amount of seats they require through a drop down menu. But what I want to do is display the number of seats that are currently free in the screen, for example if a screen has 50 seats and 7 have been booked I want the system to display: "There are 43 seats available." I know I will need a method for this but am unsure about how I would implement it and how I would show this message.

It is worth noting that a seat would only be booked for one showing, so it would be free for others, which means that the method would have to be able to count the amount of seats available for that showing.

Can someone please help.

bookings/form.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for @booking do |f| %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :user_id %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :showing_id %>

    <%= image_tag "thor_hammer.jpg",:size => "900x250" %>
    <h1>NEW BOOKING:</h1>
    <tr>
        <td width="350px">
            <br><%= f.label :seats_quantity, 'Please Select The Amount of Seats Required:' %>
        </td>
        <td width="300px">
            <br><%= f.select :seats_quantity, '1'..'10' %><br>
        </td>
        <td width="300px">
            <div class="actions">
                 <br><%= f.submit 'Book Showing' %>
            </div>
            <br><%= render "/error_messages", :message_header => "Cannot save: ", :target => @booking %> 
        </td>
    </tr>
<% end %>
```

Screen.rb:

```
class Screen < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :seats
   has_many :showings
   def screens_info
       "#{name}"
   end
end
```

Seat.rb:

```
class Seat < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :screen
end
```

Booking.rb:

```
class Booking < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :showing
end
```

Showing.rb:

```
class Showing < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :film
   has_many :bookings
   belongs_to :screen
end
```

Schema:

```
create_table "bookings", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "showing_id"
    t.integer  "seats_quantity"
end

create_table "screens", force: :cascade do |t|
   t.string   "name"
end

create_table "showings", force: :cascade do |t|
   t.date     "show_date"
   t.time     "show_time"
   t.integer  "film_id"
   t.integer  "screen_id"
end

create_table "seats", force: :cascade do |t|
   t.string   "row_letter"
   t.integer  "row_number"
   t.integer  "screen_id"
end
```

It is worth noting that whilst the `seats` table contains the attributes `row_letter` and `row_number` a user IS NOT booking a specific seat, just the quantity of seats they require.

Comment: You need some way to relate the showings to the seats directly, which you do not currently appear to have. Perhaps make a table called "seat_reservations" which contains a seat_id, showing_id, and a user_id?

Comment: Couldn't I just do that by adding in `seat_id` to the bookings table and then have the user select a specific seat? The only problem with what I've just said is that I need the user to be able to book multiple seats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Screen` class add:

```
has_many :bookings, through: :showings
```

And then your code becomes something like:

```
def remaining_seats
  seats.count - bookings.sum(:seats_quantity)  # <-- edited when I realized there was a quantity in a booking
end

def screens_info
  "#{name} (#{remaining_seats}/#{seats.count} remaining)"
end
```

Comment: How do I then make the output visible on the bookings/_form.html.erb view? I've just put the above code in the screen.rb model and then have placed this in the view: `<%= screens_info %>` but I get the error: `undefined local variable or method `screens_info'`

Comment: Well, that's another question, I had assumed that the method that you have in your own question worked!  Anyway, you don't have your controller visibile to answer **this** question, but based on what I can see in your view you could use `<%= @booking.showing.screen.screens_info %>` - but I would probably recommend setting that up better in your controller.

Comment: That doesn't work, it'll tell me that there's 20/20 seats remaining, when it should be 3/20 remaining.

Comment: ...then you don't have any bookings for that showing. I do see an error in my code (but it wouldn't explain the results you got) because I didn't notice the `seats_quantity` until now. I've updated my answer.

Comment: FWIW, here's a gist of a `rails console` with your app loaded, just to demonstrate that my code works precisely as I have detailed here: https://gist.github.com/smathy/54684059db7f4a12341b

Comment: My bad, was on the wrong showing. Sorry was being an idiot not concentrating. Your code works fine. Sorry.

Comment: screens_info has no business in a model.

Answer (score 0):

You need to figure out two values: the total seats for a specific showing and how many of those seats are already booked. Supposing you have two variables called `scr_id` and `shw_id` where the first represents the Screen Id and the second the Showing Id.

Total seats:

```
total_seats = Seat.where(screen_id: scr_id).count
```

Total bookings:

```
total_bookings = Booking.where(showing_id: shw_id).count
```

And then you only need to compute the differente between both.

```
available_seats = total_seats - total_bookings
```

**EDIT: SPECIFIC IMPLEMENTATION**

It should be implemented as a method in the screen model:

```
def available_seatings(shw_id)
    total_seats = Seat.where(screen_id: this.id).count
    total_bookings = Booking.where(showing_id: shw_id).count
    return total_seats - total_bookings
end
```

Then in the controller

```
@available_seatings = screen.available_seatings(shw_id)
```

You can then use the `@available_seatings` variable in the view

Comment: And where do I put these? In the screen.rb model?

Comment: Yeah, you create a method in the model like `def total_seats` and you call it in the controller or in the view, the method would then need to take a Screen ID and a Show ID to work

Comment: And how do I make the output of available_seats visible in the view?

Comment: You do something like that in the controller: `@available_seats = total_seats(screenid, showid)` and in the view `<%= @available_seats %>`

Comment: How do I put it in the controller? Can you please show me the code you'd add in the screens_controller? Sorry I'm pretty new to rails

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

The manual way of doing this would be like so:

```
class Showing < ActiveRecord::Base
  def booked_seats
    bookings.pluck(:seats_quantity).sum
  end

  def available_seats
    seats.count - booked_seats
  end
end
```

**OLD**

This looks like a good use of Rails' `counter_cache`.

```
class Booking < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :showing, counter_cache: true
end
```

This will store the count in a column on the Showing model (which you have to add). Then when you do `@showing.bookings.size` (not count), it will refer to that column.

"With this declaration, Rails will keep the cache value up to date, and then return that value in response to the size method." http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: That hasn't worked, I get the error: `NoMethodError in Bookings#new  undefined method bookings for nil:NilClass`

Comment: Looks like you haven't defined `@showing`? Looking at your template, looks like you'd have to do `@booking.showing.bookings.size`.

Comment: That just shows me the amount of bookings that have been made for that showing, not the amount of seats booked.